# Use nmcli to set the "all users may connect to this network" checkbox?

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

In the NetworkManager gui, under Edit Connections, there is a checkbox for "All users may connect to this network".  How can I set this option using nmcli?

Answer (score 4):

At least on my Ubuntu 18.04 Budgie system with nmcli version 1.10.6<sup>1</sup>, it seems to be possible by setting an empty value for the `connection.permissions` property

```
nmcli con modify <id> connection.permissions ''
```

where `<id>` is the connection ID (as determined via `nmcli con show` for example). See `nmcli con help` for additional options and complete syntax.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm qualifying this since the `nmcli` API has historically evolved quite rapidly between versions.